# Button from dashbord.xml not accessed in MainActivity

Tags: java, android, android-layout

App Crashed after running
I am Use standard model Bottom Navigation Acticity
I edit only fragment_dashbord.xml and MainActivity.java
Its my Codes

[image: MainActivity.java]

[image: fragment_dashbord]

Comment: You can't initialize the variables before inflating the layout. So, declare the button as  `Button button;` and initialize it in `onCreate()` as `button = findViewById(R.id.button);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Remove** `Button button = findViewById(....)` as initialization.

Just put this line in the `onCreate` method after the `setContentView(...)`

Something like:

```
Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you տյու իմ ախպերն էս բռատտ էս 3 օրա տանջվմ եմ չի ստացվմ ապրես իմ շուրիկ ախպեր